# toolbar=0 not working for firefox while hidding the toolbar of pdf so How to hide pdf toolbar in firefox

Tags: pdf, toolbar

I want to hide pdf toolbar from browser so i used toolbar=0 but it did not work on firefox but it worked in google chrome,
 so how to hide pdf toolbar in firefox.

i used this url to hide toolbar on firefox browser

path-of-pdf#toolbar=0

i have tried this also:

abc.pdf#toolbar=0&scrollbar=0&navpanes=1

but still not working in firefox.
   so please tell me how to hide the toolbar in firefox.